# PHP reference full path to Class Variable

Tags: php, class

I need to easily reference a specific path to a class variable that I can use later (like arrays). Is this possible?

```
‌‌echo $contract[0]->personnel_requirements->m->day->d7 // This works like expected

$p = "personnel_requirements->m->day->d7";

echo $contract[0]->$p; // This doesn't work :(
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you want to do this, but here is an idea:

```
$p = "A->B->C";
$pl = explode("->", $p);
$X = $contract[0];
foreach($pl as $v) {
    $X = $X->{$v};
}
echo $X;
```

Comment: Ah what a cool solution. I approached the problem differently though and just assigned each level to a different var